# How to change color of a link from black to red and back to black when clicked again

Tags: javascript

the situation is  that I have an index from A to Z and when I click on a letter the corresponding div is shown. When the same letter is clicked again, the div collapses.

What I want to achieve is, when I click a letter for the first time it should change the color of the letter in the vertical aligned index at the top to red. When clicked again from red back to black.

The solution I've found reseted the color when another letter was clicked. So the thing is that multiple divs will be active and multiple letter should be red. However, I could not get it working.

I know javascript is the solution but I'm not a good java coder. I tried inner/outerHTML and getElementbyID but every attemp was a failure.

I hope someone can help. A short solution for 3 letters would be enough.

The code can be found at http://www.webpati.com/index.txt

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java is not Javascript, you need to post more code, you would have to change the style.color attribute with javascript, or, and this is probably the better way to do it, change the class with obj.className.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! [Stack Overflow is not like all those other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554), you get out what you put in.

Comment: Java is to Javascript what ham is to hamster

Comment: Yeah, I meant Javascript. Sorry for my lack in terminology.

Comment: You can probably do this simply with css.  Simply add a class with jquery to the letter when you click on it.

Comment: I tried a couple solutions but it interferred with an accordion menu which I've not included in the code

Comment: If you want our help debugging that then you'll need to include the entirety of the code... :)

Comment: Wait a sec I'm updating the code.

Comment: I've uploaded everything to http://webpati.com/index2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

to your jQuery click function near the bottom, and add a css rule like

```
.slick-toggle { color: black; }
.slick-toggle.active { color: red; }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AzJk6/1/)

Comment: I tried a couple solutions but it interferred with an accordion menu which I've not included in the code in my prior post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer jsfiddle. At the end of the javascript I put it the code - in bold below - and it worked.

```
jQuery("a.slick-toggle").click(function () {

 if($(this).children("span").text() == "") {

    $(this).children("span").text('');

      } else {

        $(this).children("span").text('Show');

      } 

var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

jQuery("#slickbox" + id).fadeToggle({

speed:200,easing : "swing"})


**$(this).toggleClass('active');**

return false;

});
```